# Are Django, node.js on the same par with Nginx?

Tags: web-server

I am quite confused about their usage and what they are. I thought all of them were web servers but in the communities, people treat them as if their usage are all different.

Can someone please point out the difference in relation to their usage?

Comment: 'Web server' is a really broad term.  More specifically, NGinx is a classic web server and proxy, while Django is an application framework for writing web apps, and Node.js is somewhere between an application framework and a conventional general purpose programming environment.

Answer (score 1):

[Node.js](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_intro.asp) and django are written in interpreted languages (javascript and python). For a fast web server, one uses compiled languages (nginx is written in C).

You can use node.js or django depending on which language you know better. You generate dynamic content with them using database and complex patterns and logic.

You use nginx to serve static content, like images. They are not usually generated by server, but served as files. This is very fast.

Here is an example how to use [nginx with node.js](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-16-04), and here is how to use [nginx with django](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html) (for that you also need a WSGI application, see the tutorial).

Comment: I also wonder if node.js and django serve dynamic data, and when nginx serves static data,  what's good about using nginx?

Comment: NGinx can also server dynamic data, either classic PHP or CGI pages, or stuff generated with the Lua module.  It can do a lot of things that Node.js and Django can't (or can't do easily), like fast on-the-fly compression, HTTP/2, complex multihosting, proxying other web apps, and enforcing complex access controls.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn Oh, So, it's really common to use them and mix them both in many applications out on the market?

Comment: @Poream3387 Generally, yes.  Nginx is one of the most popular reverse proxy options, and is pretty popular as a simple front-end server for other web applications because it's dead simple to configure.  Apache probably still has a higher market share, but I would be willing to bet that that's more because of momentum than actual technical reasons.

Comment: @Poream3387 yes, it is the most common. I've used only django with nginx (not node.js), but in their documentation it is stated "Configure your web server to serve the files in STATIC_ROOT under the URL STATIC_URL. " https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/deployment/ So yes, it is recommended to use both nginx and django if you use django.